# Hide category description for all users and visitors

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I am using Astra Theme + Elementor and WooCommerce. I have added the following styling rule in the custom CSS section of the Astra theme to hide the category description in the category archives:

```
.term-description {
    display: none;
}
```

However, it hides only for the admin when logged in. When I log out, I still can see the category description, How can I please fix this to hide the category description for everyone (all users and visitors)?

For example, one of the category pages I need to hide the description for 
https://electrobayti.ma/petit-electromenager/mixeur/

I was expecting to hide the category description for all users and visitors.

Comment: .term-description{display:none !important;} replace with your current css

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CSS, you can try the following function to hide description from category archives:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'remove_category_archive_description', 2 );
function remove_category_archive_description(){
    if( is_product_category() ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works *(using Storefront theme).*